# Can I use material-components-android with React-Native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, material-components-android

I realized that there are not many libraries with React-Native that work with Google Material Design.
On the other hand, Google has been publishing components for the mobile apps.

I am wondering if I am targeting android, can I use https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android library with React Native?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use [material-components/material-components-android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)
But fortunately, there's [callstack/react-native-paper](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper)